# How to make woocommerce product tags hierarchical?

Tags: wordpress, tags, woocommerce, hierarchy, taxonomy

I want to change the product tags in woocommerce to display as hierarchical.
I tried to look for a function or a hook to change this but can't find any.

Will appreciate any help or suggestion to accomplish this.

Thank you.

Comment: I am already using categories.

Answer (score 7):

Tested on woocommerce 3.0.4

```
function my_woocommerce_taxonomy_args_product_tag( $array ) {
    $array['hierarchical'] = true;
    return $array;
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_taxonomy_args_product_tag', 'my_woocommerce_taxonomy_args_product_tag', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, here it is if someone is looking to do the same:

```
function reregister_taxonomy_pro_tags() {
    # the post types that the taxonomy is registered to
    $post_types = array('product');
    # set this to the taxonomy name
    $tax_name = 'product_tag';
    # load the already created taxonomy as array so we can
    # pass it back in as $args to register_taxonomy
    $tax = (array)get_taxonomy($tax_name);

    if ($tax) {
        # adjust the hierarchical necessities
        $tax['hierarchical'] = true;
        $tax['rewrite']['hierarchical'] = true;

        # adjust the hierarchical niceties (these could be ignored)
        $tax['labels']['parent_item'] = sprintf(__("Parent %s"),
        $tax->labels->singular_name);
        $tax['labels']['parent_item_colon'] = sprintf(__("Parent %s:"),
        $tax->labels->singular_name);

        # cast caps to array as expected by register_taxonomy
        $tax['capabilities'] = (array)$tax['cap'];
        # cast labels to array
        $tax['labels'] = (array)$tax['labels'];
        # register the taxonomy with our new settings
        register_taxonomy($tax_name, array('product'), $tax);
    }
}
```

## init action with a late priority so other taxonomies are loaded

add_action('init', 'reregister_taxonomy_pro_tags', 9999);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above answer saved me a ton of research but you should replace

```
    $tax['labels']['parent_item'] = sprintf(__("Parent %s"),
    $tax->labels->singular_name);
    $tax['labels']['parent_item_colon'] = sprintf(__("Parent %s:"),
    $tax->labels->singular_name);
```

to

```
$tax['labels']->parent_item = sprintf(__("Parent %s"),
$tax['labels']->singular_name);
$tax['labels']->parent_item_colon = sprintf(__("Parent %s:"),
$tax['labels']->singular_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it for WooCommerce 3.4.5 (and WordPress 4.9.8). This is based on @user2293554's answer.

```
<?php
function add_hierarchical_product_tags( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ) {
    if ( $taxonomy == 'product_tag' && $args['hierarchical'] != true ) {
        $args['hierarchical'] = true;
        $args['rewrite']['hierarchical'] = true;

        // Update CMS labels
        $args['labels']->parent_item = sprintf(__("Parent %s"), $args['labels']->singular_name);
        $args['labels']->parent_item_colon = sprintf(__("Parent %s:"), $args['labels']->singular_name);

        // Convert to array for register_taxonomy()
        $args['labels'] = (array)$args['labels'];
        $args['capabilities'] = (array)$args['cap'];
        unset( $args['cap'] );  // remove the cap object

        register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args );
    }
}

add_action( 'registered_taxonomy', 'add_hierarchical_product_tags', 10, 3 );
```

The `args['hierarchical'] != true` condition is needed so we don't get stuck in a loop, as the `registered_taxonomy` action will get called again.